# Storing characters and integers

Tags: c++

What type can I use to store both integers and characters?

For example say if I wanted to make a variable for a barcode, what type would I use? I've used `string` but the program seems to act weird when I input integers and characters, any help?

Thanks!

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show some code. What does "act weird" mean? What are you even trying to do, on the big picture?

Comment: If you want print it, you must add '0' to every digit in the string

Comment: In general it depends on the actual barcode format (there are several). But in general a barcode isn’t a mix of integers and characters. It’s a *sequence of digits*, where each digit can be either a numeric or non-numeric character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::string`, so your barcode variable will look like this:

```
std::string barcode;
```

Hope this helps mate!

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This actually works, thank you Finn. What does the 'std::' do?

Comment: Also, how do I read the entire line? When I input spaces it only shows the code before the space?

Comment: Ah, you need to read the entire line, to do that, use `std::getline(cin,barcode);`

Comment: @David I don't understand why it should be a comment, especially due to the fact that I solved his/her problem. Please explain?

Comment: Because, you gave absolutely no explanation as to why, and, as a general rule of thumb, if you're not elaborating, and it fits in a comment, it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to store something like "ABC123", then just use a string.

Now, if you're trying to convert an `int` to a string, and have no reason for the `int`, aside from that you're reading numbers then just read them in to a `string` object, not an `int` object.

If you need to preserve both the text, and integers seprately, then you'll want to use a `class` structure. You can then add methods to that class which can output the alphanumeric value out as a string.